# How can restore wordpress backup?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

we created a wordpress website , then we need to update wordpress version we take full backup from cpanel ,after updated the website lost a lot of data and setting we tried to restore the backup from cpanel and it did not work 
any idea about how to restore the backup and return to the Previous version of wordpress ?

Comment: I'd suggest posting to the [WordPress stackexchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) for WP-specific questions. As this isn't a programming question, it's off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

To answer this Question the best way please send more information the next time for example the error etc.

So the only answer i can give to you is in gerneral:

In case you got a backup of all folders, files and a dump of the old database you can restore your old WP version

- Just Upload your Files to your server but make sure you have also a Backup of your current WP just in case!
- Import the Dump from the Database to your Databaseserver in most cases it is MySQL and make a dump of the current Wp-database just in case and also make your old DB got the same name as in your Configs. so that wordpress can find the DB.
- Check whether the Website is working
- If the website is not working got to your wp-config and have a look at your settings like DB user, password ....

You can also look for more Information on YouTube there are many Tutorials on this topic

Hope i can help you and have a nice day.

Also good Luck :D

Comment: Thanks a lot , I will try

Comment: you are Welcome